# How do i validate and assign my output in a simple way

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, one-liner

Is it possible to do something like this in python:

I have a single `'span'` that I want to scrape.

I just want to simplify how I get the data, I will get an error if I convert the bs4 instance to text if it is `None`. and in general it would be nice if python had some kind of functionality like this. :-)

```py
note = x.text for event.find('span', {'class': 'header-3'}) as x if not None else ''
```

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

So far i solved my issue with bs4 by making a function that i can apply on all my bs4 instances:

```py
get_text = lambda x: x.text.strip() if x is not None else ''
note = get_text(event.find('span', {'class': 'header-3'}))
```

But it would still be nice to know if there was a nice way like the one in my first codeblock.

Comment: You need a list comprehension. Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it

Comment: Sorry I think I wasnt clear in my question. I am not working with a list. This is a single entity

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
event = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
note = event.findAll('span', {'class': 'header-3'})
```

Comment: Sorry I think I wasnt clear in my question. I am not working with a list. This is a single entity

Comment: Are you asking how to get the one and only span with class: header-3 as text if it exists?  Some example data and the expected results would help figure out what you need.

Comment: So here is an example just to show a working example, but what I really wanted to ask is if there is a way to do what I did without the lambda function. Some kind of fancy python feature or different thinking that lets me write one line less  :-) https://codeshare.io/5O1k3x

Comment: I see.  I think the lambda is the most elegant and readable way.  I can think of several other possibilities, but none result in one less line of code :)